# Inserting code from a string or array in to whiptail

Tags: linux, string, shell, insert

I am new to Linux, the shell and scripts.  I have come across a problem I can't find the answer to no matter how much I try to Google.

I have a script which creates menu items for a program called "whiptail" which seems to be the standard way to show dialog boxes and menu items on Debian for the Raspberry Pi.  The list items are created based on various data found in various files on the Linux box.  My code starts

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The list is created in the #!/bin/sh environment at the top of the script.

However, for examples sake lets define the list as:

```
LIST="\"Tag 1\" \"Item 1\" \\ \n\"Tag 2\" \"Item 2\" \\ \n"
```

The code that works is:

```
while true; do
 TESTRESULT=$(whiptail --menu "Test" 20 80 12 --cancel-button Cancel --ok-button Select \
  "Tag 1" "Item 1" \
  "Tag 2" "Item 2" \
   3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
 RET=$?
 if [ $RET -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "Cancel"
   exit 0
 elif [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Do something with the selection stored in TESTRESULT"
   exit 0
 else
   exit 1
 fi
```

I can't figure out how to replace

```
  "Tag 1" "Item 1" \
  "Tag 2" "Item 2" \
```

with the items in the "LIST" variable.  I have a feeling the answer lies with "eval" but I am having issues getting that to work as a solution also.

I am also playing around with creating LIST as an array, but I think that complicates things also.

Any one kindly got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have also realized that the "\" at the end of each menu item is probably telling the shell to "Treat as one line" rather than separating the Menu items, but after re-formatting "LINE" to act as a one-line list, I still have issues using

```
"TESTRESULT=$(whiptail --menu "Test" 20 80 12 --cancel-button Cancel --ok-button Select $LIST 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

I am wondering if it something to do with $LIST being used in a $() container.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind figured it out.  The issue was the way the string was being broken up.  Changing the IFS (Internal field separator) and changing it back again allowed me to use spaces where I wanted them:

```
oIFS="$IFS";
IFS="/"

LIST="Tag 1/Item 1/Tag 2/Item 2"

while true; do
 TESTRESULT=$(whiptail --menu "Test" 20 80 12 --cancel-button Cancel --ok-button Select $LIST 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) 
 RET=$?
 if [ $RET -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Cancel"
  exit 0
 elif [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Do something with the selection stored in TESTRESULT"
  exit 0
 else
  exit 1
 fi
done

IFS=$oIFS
```